# How to Display image from path in pdf header using jsPDF-autotable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am generating html to pdf using jsPDF jsPDF-autotable, the header, and footer is being printed well. I have tried adding a logo to the header but it is failing to print it, when I `console.log(base64Img)` and convert it, it is the same logo.

This is the code to convert image to base64 string

```
imgToBase64 (url, callback) {
        if (!window.FileReader) {
            callback(null);
            return;
        }
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.onload = function () {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function () {
                callback((reader.result as string).replace('text/xml', 'image/jpeg'));
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.send();
```

And this is the code to generate the pdf

```
generatePDF() {

        let base64Img = null;
        this.imgToBase64(this.imageURL, (base64) => {
          base64Img = base64;
          console.log('image in base 64', base64Img);

          const doc = new jspdf('p', 'pt', 'a4');
          const header = function(headerData: any) {
            doc.setFontSize(20);
            doc.setTextColor(0, 190, 208);
            doc.setFontStyle('normal');
            if (this.base64Img) {
              doc.addImage(this.base64Img, 'JPEG', headerData.settings.margin.left, 15, 60, 10);
              doc.setFontSize(20);
            }
            doc.text('Header Title', headerData.settings.margin.left, 60);
            const currentdate = new Date();
            const datetime = currentdate.getDate() + '/' + (currentdate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + currentdate.getFullYear();
            doc.text('Date: ' + datetime, headerData.settings.margin.left + 400, 60);
            doc.setFontSize(5);
          };

          const totalPagesExp = '{total_pages_count_string}';
          const footer = function(footerData) {
            doc.setFontSize(10);
            let str = 'Page ' + footerData.pageCount;
            // Total page number plugin only available in jspdf v1.0+
            if (typeof doc.putTotalPages === 'function') {
              str = str + ' of ' + totalPagesExp;
              console.log('test');
            }
            doc.text(str, footerData.settings.margin.left, doc.internal.pageSize.height - 10);
            doc.text('https://wwww.example.com', footerData.settings.margin.left + 400, doc.internal.pageSize.height - 10);
          };

          const head = [['Name', 'Phone', 'Email', 'Gender', 'Location', 'Country']]

          const options = {
            beforePageContent: header,
            afterPageContent: footer,
            margin: {
              top: 100
            },
            head: head,
            columnStyles: {
              0: {columnWidth: 100},
              1: {columnWidth: 80},
              2: {columnWidth: 80},
              3: {columnWidth: 50},
            }
          };

          const elem = document.getElementById('pdfContent');
          const data = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(elem);
          doc.autoTable( data.columns, data.rows, options);

          // Total page number plugin only available in jspdf v1.0+
          if (typeof doc.putTotalPages === 'function') {
            doc.putTotalPages(totalPagesExp);
          }

          doc.save('generated.pdf');
          });
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I thing i'm too late, but this will help others.

you can use like

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');

var header = function (data) {
    doc.setFontSize(18);
    doc.setTextColor(40);
    doc.setFontStyle('normal');
    doc.addImage(base64_source, 'JPEG', data.settings.margin.left, 20, 50, 50);
    //doc.addImage(image base64_source, 'image format', logo_sizes.centered_x, _y, logo_sizes.w, logo_sizes.h);
    //Image must be Base64 encoded
};

doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {margin: {top: 80}, beforePageContent: header});

doc.save("test.pdf");
```

**Note:** you have to use with your code variables this is only demo.

Comment: As you can see, I have the image in there, but it is only printing other details without the image.